# Use Magento SOAP API to login in iOS App

Tags: ios, magento, soap

I am new to Magento and looking for solution to allow iOS app (in Swift) to be able to login to Magento using the SOAP or REST API. I am using Community Edition of Magento and I am using SOAPEngine (https://github.com/priore/SOAPEngine) for sending SOAP request.

Your help highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to fetch data from Magento to iOs  or iOS to Magento?

Comment: Thanks Muk. I want to create a custom login view controller from iOS to login into Magento. So, i want to send my username and password to Magento and perform the authentication on the backend side.